# How to plot multiple daily time series, aligned at specified trigger times?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, seaborn

**The Problem:**

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
                                  value  msg_type
date        
2022-03-15 08:15:10+00:00         122    None
2022-03-15 08:25:10+00:00         125    None
2022-03-15 08:30:10+00:00         126    None
2022-03-15 08:30:26.542134+00:00  127    ANNOUNCEMENT
2022-03-15 08:35:10+00:00         128    None
2022-03-15 08:40:10+00:00         122    None
2022-03-15 08:45:09+00:00         127    None
2022-03-15 08:50:09+00:00         133    None
2022-03-15 08:55:09+00:00         134    None
....
2022-03-16 09:30:09+00:00         132    None
2022-03-16 09:30:13.234425+00:00  135    ANNOUNCEMENT
2022-03-16 09:35:09+00:00         130    None
2022-03-16 09:40:09+00:00         134    None
2022-03-16 09:45:09+00:00         135    None
2022-03-16 09:50:09+00:00         134    None
```

The `value` data occurs in roughly 5 minute intervals, but messages can occur at any time. I am trying to plot one line of `values` per day, where the x-axis ranges from t=-2 hours to t=+8 hours, and the `ANNOUNCEMENT` occurs at t=0 (see image below).

So, for example, if an `ANNOUNCEMENT` occurs at 8:30AM on 3/15 and again at 9:30AM on 3/16, there should be two lines:

- one line for 3/15 that plots data from 6:30AM to 4:30PM, and
- one line for 3/16 that plots data from 7:30AM to 5:30PM,

both sharing the same x-axis ranging from -2 to +8, with `ANNOUNCEMENT` at t=0.

---

**What I've Tried:**

I am able to do this currently by finding the index position of an announcement (e.g. say it occurs at row 298 -> `announcement_index = 298`), generating an array of 120 numbers from -24 to 96 (representing 10 hours at 5 minutes per number -> `x = np.arange(-24, 96, 1)`), then plotting

```
sns.lineplot(x, y=df['value'].iloc[announcement_index-24:announcement_index+96])
```

While this does mostly work (see image below), I suspect it's not the correct way to go about it. Specifically, trying to add more info to the plot (like a different set of 'value' markers) at specific times is difficult because I would need to convert the timestamp into this arbitrary 24-96 value range.

**How can I make this same plot but by utilizing the datetime index instead?** Thank you so much!

[image: Announcement Profile Plot]

Comment: @not_speshal you are correct, I cannot have datetime on the x-axis. I guess I am looking for a way to generate the plot using datetime, then editing the labels after the fact to be -2 to +8 hours? The way I described in the OP was the only way I could think to do it, but it felt very hacked together and I was hoping to find a more pythonic method for it, if that makes sense.

Comment: Could you include your expected output for your sample data? Both your announcements occur on the same date in your sample.

Comment: @not_speshal sure, I will actually update the sample data to reflect the situation a little better. Sorry for not having it that way in the first place, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the index has already been converted [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), create an [`IntervalArray`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.arrays.IntervalArray.html) from -2H to +8H of the index:

```
dl, dr = -2, 8
left = df.index + pd.Timedelta(f'{dl}H')
right = df.index + pd.Timedelta(f'{dr}H')

df['interval'] = pd.arrays.IntervalArray.from_arrays(left, right)
```

Then for each `ANNOUNCEMENT`, plot the window from `interval.left` to `interval.right`:

- Set the x-axis as seconds since `ANNOUNCEMENT`
- Set the labels as hours since `ANNOUNCEMENT`

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for ann in df.loc[df['msg_type'] == 'ANNOUNCEMENT'].itertuples():
    window = df.loc[ann.interval.left:ann.interval.right] # extract interval.left to interval.right
    window.index -= ann.Index                             # compute time since announcement
    window.index = window.index.total_seconds()           # convert to seconds since announcement

    window.plot(ax=ax, y='value', label=ann.Index.date())
    deltas = np.arange(dl, dr + 1)
    ax.set(xticks=deltas * 3600, xticklabels=deltas)      # set tick labels to hours since announcement

ax.legend()
```

Here is the output with a smaller window -1H to +2H just so we can see the small sample data more clearly (full code below):

[image]

Full code:

```
import io
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = '''
date,value,msg_type
2022-03-15 08:15:10+00:00,122,None
2022-03-15 08:25:10+00:00,125,None
2022-03-15 08:30:10+00:00,126,None
2022-03-15 08:30:26.542134+00:00,127,ANNOUNCEMENT
2022-03-15 08:35:10+00:00,128,None
2022-03-15 08:40:10+00:00,122,None
2022-03-15 08:45:09+00:00,127,None
2022-03-15 08:50:09+00:00,133,None
2022-03-15 08:55:09+00:00,134,None
2022-03-16 09:30:09+00:00,132,None
2022-03-16 09:30:13.234425+00:00,135,ANNOUNCEMENT
2022-03-16 09:35:09+00:00,130,None
2022-03-16 09:40:09+00:00,134,None
2022-03-16 09:45:09+00:00,135,None
2022-03-16 09:50:09+00:00,134,None
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), index_col=0, parse_dates=['date'])

# create intervals from -1H to +2H of the index
dl, dr = -1, 2
left = df.index + pd.Timedelta(f'{dl}H')
right = df.index + pd.Timedelta(f'{dr}H')
df['interval'] = pd.arrays.IntervalArray.from_arrays(left, right)

# plot each announcement's interval.left to interval.right
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for ann in df.loc[df['msg_type'] == 'ANNOUNCEMENT')].itertuples():
    window = df.loc[ann.interval.left:ann.interval.right] # extract interval.left to interval.right
    window.index -= ann.Index                             # compute time since announcement
    window.index = window.index.total_seconds()           # convert to seconds since announcement

    window.plot(ax=ax, y='value', label=ann.Index.date())
    deltas = np.arange(dl, dr + 1)
    ax.set(xticks=deltas * 3600, xticklabels=deltas)      # set tick labels to hours since announcement

ax.grid()
ax.legend()
```

Comment: Thanks @tdy, this is exactly what I was looking for. Just to make sure I'm understanding that first block correctly, you are creating a new column `interval` that serves as the boundaries for where you would plot from, such that every row has an interval value from -2 to +8 hours. Then you just select the window for that row when you plot. Excellent! And I assume the traces in the graph are slightly out of line because you had to modify the data for the example, yes? (e.g. on 3/15 it should be 135 at t=0, but your graph shows 130, but this is because you changed the time?) Thank you!!

Comment: @walker967 Re: interval logic, yep that's correct. Re: graph output, actually there was a bug in my original code which should now be fixed. Note that the index (x-axis) is now explicitly defined as seconds-since-announcement (and then relabled as hours-since-announcement).

Comment: sorry to bother regarding your old answer but I am revisiting this for another project and when I try to implement `df.index + pd.Timedelta('8H')` I get an error `TypeError: Concatenation operation is not implemented for NumPy arrays, use np.concatenate() instead. Please do not rely on this error; it may not be given on all Python implementations.` Do you get this same error, and if so do you know a way to remedy it? Thanks so much.

Comment: @walker967 Double check whether `df.index` is a true datetime dtype. If `print(df.index.dtype)` does not show something like `dtype('<M8[ns]')`, then convert it with `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`

Comment: Ah, that was it - I didn't have my index set as the date column and was instead using the default index. Duh! Thank you so much again for all your help.